# URL Problem with ASP to ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, url, url-rewriting, seo, url-routing

I will transfer a website from CLASSIC ASP to ASP.NET. My domain name will not change but urls will change For Example: http://www.etkinpatent.com/iso-8-40-iso-9001-nedir.html this link will change to http://www.etkinpatent.com/iso-9001-nedir.html robots will give to my links too much bad points. How can ı solve this problem?

Comment: I added a SEO tag because this question seems about search engines optimization. Feel free to remove if I got it wrong.

Comment: I think SEO tag is appropriate. The OP's mentioned concern about bad points from robots.

Comment: Couldn't you just use a `301` (permanent) redirect?

Comment: Give me some examples please. I am new in ASP.NET

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [ASP.NET Routing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/cc668201.aspx) to redirect any url to the page you want.

In your Global.asax file, add something like this (assuming you use ASP.NET 4.0):

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RegisterRoutes(System.Web.Routing.RouteTable.Routes);
}

void RegisterRoutes(System.Web.Routing.RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.MapPageRoute("OldPageRoute", "oldpage.html", "~/NewPage.aspx");
}
```

If you now call oldpage.html, you will see the content of NewPage.aspx.

This is a good solution if you want to stick to your old page names. If you would rather use new page names, but are worried about Google, use 301 redirects, like Smirkin Gherkin said in the comments.